# Trying to add a Wordpress header to the top of a SMF, but the stylesheets are mixed up

Tags: wordpress, web, stylesheet, smf

I have a Wordpress site (installed in root) and a Simple Machines Forum (in /forums).  I've spent hours trying to add the Wordpress header over the SMF, but with little luck.  I've probably looked at 50+ guides on the subject as well, but the only things that remotely worked was an iframe (which somehow messed up sessions or something with the forum).  So don't think I haven't try it myself before asking you guys.

Anyway, what usually happens appears to be stylesheet mixing: I can get parts of the header to display, but it seems like the SMF theme stylesheets are messing it up.  For example, see this picture:

http://gyazo.com/62551a8b45b7e50c2a41684da7b261f8.png

I've tried:

- Using a simple Wordpress get_header() function after including wp-blog-header.php
- This guide: http://www.nutt.net/2009/08/16/how-to-wrap-a-smf-forum-in-wordpress/
- Laboriously recreating the header using more unique ids, etc., in an attempt to avoid CSS overlap.
- Using JQuery's .load.
- Using an iframe.  Yay for ancient iframes; only it came close.

I basically just want my Wordpress header displaying over the SMF, and then hiding the SMF (probably with display:none or something).

Please advise...my eyes hurt from working on this way too much.  Thanks!

Comment: No one has any thoughts?  I'd appreciate even a link or something, heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a working answer.  I basically used the CSS descendant selectors to apply the Wordpress styles only to the header.  So, I took the id of the div surrounding the header (for example, "wp-header"), and then added `#wp-header` to the beginning of each CSS selector in Wordpress's stylesheet (using a copy for the header, of course; I also deleted a lot of irrelevant styles).  Notepad++'s macros were quite useful.

I am not sure if there was a more elegant solution, but this to be holding up.